# R Apply user-defined function to selected columns of a dataframe

Tags: r, function, loops, lapply

I am trying to apply a user-defined function (fitdistr from the MASS package) to selected columns of a dataframe, but I keep getting the error "'x' must be a non-empty numeric vector". I am looking to use the lapply() function or loop through the selected columns. How can I proceed?
Here is the function defined:

```
SSD <- function(x,p){
      #fitting model through MSC10 
      SSD.params <- fitdistr(x,"log-normal")
      HC20 <- qlnorm(p, meanlog = SSD.params$estimate[1], sdlog = SSD.params$estimate[2])
      return(HC20)
    }
```

my dataframe looks something like that

```
   A       B      C     D     
1  AB     1.5    3.1   8.7
2  CD     0.15   10.7 16.2
3  EF     3.6    5.4   4.7
4  GH     2.8    6.1   1.8
```

I've got 1003 columns, and I would like to apply the function to column 4:1003 (all rows) and save the output in a dataframe with 1 row and 1003 columns (results of the qlnorm function above).
Any ideas on how to best do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please add the code you're using right now to launch `SSD` with `lapply`?

Comment: 'num_col2 <- seq(4,1003,1)
boot.HC20 <- as.data.frame(lapply(boot.MSC10[, num_col2], SSD))' This actually worked now but I'd like to keep some information (value in one column) in the output dataframe. not sure how to do that

Comment: you are missing a value for `p` in your code. It should be: `boot.HC20 <- as.data.frame(lapply(boot.MSC10[, num_col2], SSD, p = <some number!>))`

Comment: Ok perfect thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
as.data.frame(t(unlist(lapply(df[,4:1003], SSD, p=p)))
```

Comment: or simply `as.data.frame(lapply(df[4:1003], SSD, p = p))`

Comment: thanks! this is equivalent to what finally worked for me (above comment), but where do I define p? here in "p=p"?

Comment: instead of `p = p` write the number you need, like `p = 0.5`